# install mac os el capital from SSD

Tags: mac, install, ssd

I bought the 450GB SSD that already have mac os el Capital file for laptop, I also bought SSD USB to connect the laptop.

Before installing it, how do I can install or set Mac os el capital from SSD into the same SSD before I replace with the hard drive!

If I'm doing wrong way, is this mean that I have to replace the hard drive with SSD first before installing it! because once I have tried that and the press Options key button is unable to read from start SSD.

I would appreciate your time with help thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling a bit with your wording so lets run through a couple standard tasks and you can let me know if I've answered your question or am way off the mark.

--Situation 1.) You have macOS 10.11 (El Capitan) installed on your MacBook's internal HDD. You want to upgrade with an SSD.

1. Attach the SSD using the USB cable.
2. Hold "Option" at boot and choose the internal HDD with macOS 10.11
3. Install CCC (https://bombich.com/software/download_ccc.php) and use it to clone the internal HDD to the external SSD. (No need to purchase unless you want to continue using as your backup software)
4. Restart.
5. Hold "Option" at boot and choose the external ssd with macOS 10.11 now on it.
6. If everything works, shutdown and replace the HDD with the SSD (Search youtube for a walkthrough for your specific model)
7. Hold "Option" at boot and choose the now internal ssd with macOS 10.11.
8. OPTIONAL: If step 2, 5, or 6 failed, Hold "CMD + Option + R" at boot to enter internet recovery. Choose disk utility. Run "First Aid" on SSD. If failed a reinstall of macOS is required. (See Additional Task below)

--Situation 2.) You have macOS 10.11 (El Capitan) installed on your External SSD. You want to upgrade the internal HDD with the SSD. I'll assume that there is nothing important on the internal HDD, but if that is incorrect, please be sure to backup your data first.

1. Attach the SSD using the USB cable.
2. Hold "Option" at boot and choose the external SSD with macOS 10.11 on it
3. If everything works, shutdown and replace the HDD with the SSD (Search youtube for a walkthrough for your specific model)
4. Hold "Option" at boot and choose the now internal ssd with macOS 10.11.
5. OPTIONAL: If step 3 or 4 failed, Hold "CMD + Option + R" at boot to enter internet recovery. Choose disk utility. Run "First Aid" on SSD. If failed a reinstall of macOS is required. (See Additional Task below)

-- Additional Task: Reinstall macOS (10.13 High Sierra will be installed)

1. Hold "CMD + Option + R" at boot to enter internet recovery.
2. Choose disk utility.
3. Ensure desired disk/volume is selected on left side.
4. Click Erase. 
   If HDD choose HFS+ / OSX Extended(Journaled) and name it "Macintosh HD"
   If SSD choose APFS and name it "Macintosh HD"
5. Quit disk utility
6. Select Install macOS High Sierra
7. Follow the steps provided to reinstall. Note that it may take far longer than stated if your internet connection is below average.